# PHP PDO multiple select query consistently dropping last rowset

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm experiencing what appears to be a bug using a PDO statement to make multiple selects.

I'm building a SQL query that has many SELECTs, and regardless of how many SELECT statements it makes, the last rowset is dropped.

Here's a truncated example of whats happening

```
$pdo = /* connection stuff here */
$sql = "select 1; select 2; select 3; select 4;";
$statement = $pdo->query($sql);

do {
    $rowset = $statement->fetchAll();
    if($rowset) {               
        // Do stuff with $rowset
    }       
} while($statement->nextRowset());
```

Doing the above, 1-3 are successfully retrieved as rowsets, but 4 is not.
I cannot explain why that is the case. Making any subsequent queries with the same PDO object results in an error:

```
PDO::query(): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. 
Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.
```

The above `do ... while ...` routine was based off of what can be found in PHP's documentation on the `nextRowset()` function at https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php

Calling `$statement->closeCursor()` at the end doesn't seem to work

The routines I'm using are significantly more complex, but I can confirm that the sql behaves as expected (by plugging it into MySQL directly using PHPMyAdmin and running it using `mysqli->multi_query()`, both of which return the expected results)

I found someone who had a similar issue and issued a PHP bug ticket, which was apparently marked as fixed: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61207&edit=1

Can anyone please explain to me what is causing the last rowset to be dropped? Thanks!

*Versions: **PHP 5.4.12**, **MySQL 5.6.12***

Edit 1:
I attempted to use MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY by changing the code to...

```
$pdo = /* connection stuff here */
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true); // added code
$sql = "select 1; select 2; select 3; select 4;";
$statement = $pdo->query($sql);

do {
    $rowset = $statement->fetchAll();
    if($rowset) {               
        // Do stuff with $rowset
    }       
} while($statement->nextRowset());
```

This didn't solve the problem

Comment: Have you tried enabling PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY?

Comment: I just did- see Edit 1

Comment: are you quite certain that the last query is terminated with a semi-colon?

Comment: it works with 4 rowsets for me. I tried removing the last semi-colon without any effect. Tampering with `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` allows or not the multiple statements to be executed. I'm running php 5.4 on MAMP.

Comment: @TimG Yes, I am. The problem will happen even if we guarantee semicolons, however. See the SQL query in my example where only ints are being selected. Even something this simple will cause the problem.

Comment: hey is it possible the last rowset is not fetched correctly? Is there a condition in your code which not being rightly evaluated would have the script fetching only one row, or none at all? That would lead the $rowset to be empty, and the $statement to be unuseable and produce your HY000 error.

Comment: I am having an identical problem (the final rowset never appears and this error is thrown).

Comment: I have posted another SO question to re-raise this issue, which strikes me as a catastrophic failure, because there is no substitute or workaround (that I yet know of) for a failed `nextRowSet()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564054/pdostatementnextrowset-is-broken-in-mysql-5-6-16-on-windows

Answer (score 3):

I think you are over complicating things with your do/while loop.

Try a simple while loop instead:

```
$pdo = /* connection stuff here */
$sql = "select 1; select 2; select 3; select 4;";
$statement = $pdo->query($sql);

while($rowset = $statement->fetchAll()){
    //do stuff

    $statement->nextRowset();
}
```

This will continue looping while rowset does not have a false value which should then work exactly as you expect.

Comment: +1 Worked... but it produces something like `array (0,1,2,3)`, `array(0,1,2,3)`, `array(0,1,2,3)`... The issue is, when you call `array[0]`, all three `arrays` `echo` their first Element so you have three `index [0]`s.... Could you know how to separate the 3 `arrays` for example save each `return`ed `array` in a separate `var`iable... cz now they are all in One.

Comment: Try using fetch instead of fetchall

Answer (score 1):

To avoid that `PDOException` just use `columnCount`:

```
while ($statment->columnCount()) {
     $rowset = $statment->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     $statment->nextRowset();
}
```