# PDOStatement::nextRowSet() is broken in MySQL 5.6.16 on Windows

Tags: php, mysql, windows, pdo

[This question without an accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485868/php-pdo-multiple-select-query-consistently-dropping-last-rowset) raises a catastrophic problem with MySQL that I am experiencing on MySQL version 5.6.16 on Windows in a modified form.

The problem is easily reproducible: I include it here (copied from the above-linked question, but with changes applicable to my code):

```
$pdo = /* connection stuff here */
$sql = "call test();"; // call stored procedure - see below
$statement = $connection->query($sql);
do {
    $rowset = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($rowset) {
        // Do stuff with $rowset
    }
} while($statement->nextRowset());
```

Here is the definition of the stored procedure `test`:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`()
BEGIN    
    SELECT 1; SELECT 2; SELECT 3; SELECT 4;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The only difference between my code, and the above-linked code, is that I pack the SQL query into a stored procedure.

In my case, the `while` statement returns `true` four times, rather than three times (it should be just three times).  After the fourth time, `fetchAll(...)` throws a `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error` error.

Unfortunately, this problem is catastrophic.  There is no other way with PDO to iterate to following rowsets other than using the `nextRowSet()` function.  Therefore, I may revert to a previous version of MySQL in order to work around this issue.

I have found two links that seem to indicate this issue, listed here:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67130 and 
http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.php.devel/81518

I would appreciate a confirmation that this is, indeed, a bug with version 5.6.16 of MySQL on Windows.  Even more, I would appreciate a workaround.  Thanks.

Comment: [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli) "can" ([as I recall](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)) switch between resultsets, but it would require to move entire application to another database interaction layer.

Comment: Why can't you run all those strings as 4 separate queries?

Comment: @silkfire I've updated my question to add important details (apologies for not doing so when I first posted the question).  The code, as it now stands, is 100% identical to what I have running.  In fact, the SQL is embedded in a stored procedure.  For my actual application, the queries are much more complex and not easily refactored.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum I actually just tried your code on my WAMP installation with MySQL 5.6.17 and it works just brilliantly as long as I enable emulated prepares with `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);`

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem with PDO::nextRowset(), as it returns true even there are no more rowsets available, therefore when calling fetchAll(), it raises exception HY000. (tested on PHP 5.5.12 windows, Mysql 5.5.17 linux)

A workaround for this problem is to check number of columns with method PDO::columnCount() before fetching rowset. If it is non-zero, you have a valid rowset, and thus you could call PDO::fetchAll().

Even if PDO::nextRowset() reports true, columnCount() will report number of columns before moving to next rowset.

Example:

```
while ($objQuery->columnCount()) {
    $tab[] = $objQuery->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $objQuery->nextRowset();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the problem is being caused by multiple result sets, then maybe the best work around would be to find ways of avoiding multiple result sets in a single query.

For example, if the expected results are in the same format (which I expect they probably are because you intend to use the same code to deal with all of them) then you could potentially use UNION to compound the four queries together.

```
SELECT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 4;
```

Failing that, you can execute a separate query for each SELECT and hand the result off to a function to do the processing.