# How is this code in PHP vulnerable to SQL Injection?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I know the basics of SQL Injection and how to avoid it.
**I know my code is vulnerable**, but I'm trying to inject SQL and it is not working. This is about knowing HOW it is vulnerable, because in practice, I cannot do it.

This is the code:

```
   $email = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'email');

   if ($email != '') { 
       try {
           $stm1 = $db->query("SELECT * from clients WHERE email =  '$email'");
           $result = $stm1->fetchAll();
       } catch (Exception $ex) {
           echo $ex->getMessage();
       }
  }
```

I'm trying to inject via this input

```
<input id="textinput" name="email" type="text">
```

and I'm using codes like:

```
'; UPDATE clients set status = 0 WHERE client_id = 1
```

Note that this is a valid SQL Query.

My real questions are:

1. Is filter_input preventing anything in this case?
2. Does PDO '$query' function ONLY allow ONE statement?
3. If this is not vulnerable in this case, are there any other cases where it would be vulnerable?

Comment: Use parameterized queries and then never have to ask this question again

Comment: I'm trying to understand other concepts, I know how to use parameterized queries, can you read the real questions on the list 1, 2 and 3, please?

Comment: no. filter input is not preventing anything. Just because you can't think of a quick way to exploit the query via something that looks like an email address, doesn't mean someone else CAN'T. You don't base your security systems on "meh, not likely to happen" and just use the tools you're already using PROPERLY: You're using PDO - use placeholders. It costs you NOTHING and you gain complete defense against injection attacks.

Comment: And yes, only one query statement per query call. That's not a PDO limit. It's a fundamental limit built into the underlying mysql drivers to prevent SOME (but definitely not all) forms of injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks for trying Marc. But this is not my question. I'm trying to BREAK MY OWN CODE. I'm not asking for advice on security. I'm gonna put this way: This is a friend's code, and I'm trying to prove that it is vulnerable. But in practice, I cannot do it. I know it is vulnerable, but I want to perform an attack, just to prove that it is vulnerable.

Comment: I see. So this is not vulnerable to that example I first gave because I can't execute 2 queries in one statement. So now I'm searching for OTHER ways to PROVE it is vulnerable. Using something practical is the only way I can prove this to him. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I think the issue here is that people will glady help to secure a site, but they are not so willing to show anyone how to exploit one. I'm sure people have asked genuine sounding questions before and then used this information against someone. We probably shouldn't be showing people how this type of thing is done, if they don't already know, lets not tell them

Comment: @Scriptable, maybe it explains it then.

Comment: Have you tried values like "`' or '' = '`"

Comment: @RowlandShaw, this is a simple query. I wanted to show the whole database is vulnerable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `$email = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'email');` does nothing it's the same as `$email = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'email', FILTER_DEFAULT);`, and `FILTER_DEFAULT` is documented as "do nothing".

Second, PDO's Query function does appear to support multiple statements (albeit in a rather annoying to use manner, and I can't say I've personally played with it). [PHP PDO multiple select query consistently dropping last rowset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485868/php-pdo-multiple-select-query-consistently-dropping-last-rowset)

Third, even without multiple statement support, `$email` could be populated with something like `nobody@example.com' OR username='admin` to return data you didn't plan on returning to the user.

**Fundamentally:** stop worrying about whether bad code is exploitable, and start writing good code instead. Start using properly prepared statements and don't worry about injection anymore.

Comment: I would upvote because this is usefull, but this is not the answer I'm looking for right now.

Comment: @MarkGoebs I answered all three of your questions. WTF?

Comment: In fact, you are right. I will accept it, but what I really wanted was an example showing that other tables of my database were vulnerable using this bad practice.